# Java - OpenCV ignoring extra contours

Tags: java, opencv

I have an image:

[image]

I want to crop it so the book is by itself.

I am using OpenCV to attempt and get the contrours of the image. Once I draw them, it looks like this. How can I ignore the extra contours to the right of the image? I have already tries using outliers with standard deviation. Right now it takes every point inside the rectanlge, and adds it to an arraylist for later processing. I have an overall arraylist for points, and 2 more so when computing statistical analysis the points can be ordered from least to greatest.

This is what it looks like now:

[image]

```
import java.awt.Point;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfPoint2f;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.imgcodecs.Imgcodecs;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;

public class imtest {



   public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
       String filename="C:/image.png";
System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
   Mat torect=new Mat();
   Mat torect1=Imgcodecs.imread(filename,0);
   Imgproc.Canny(torect1, torect, 10, 100); 


   List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();  
   Imgproc.findContours(torect.clone(), contours, new Mat(),        Imgproc.RETR_LIST,Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
   ArrayList<Point> outlie=new ArrayList<Point>();
   ArrayList<Integer> ylist=new ArrayList<Integer>();
   ArrayList<Integer> xlist=new ArrayList<Integer>();

          MatOfPoint2f approxCurve = new MatOfPoint2f();

          //For each contour found
          for (int i=0; i<contours.size(); i++)
          {
              //Convert contours(i) from MatOfPoint to MatOfPoint2f
              MatOfPoint2f contour2f = new MatOfPoint2f( contours.get(i).toArray() );
              //Processing on mMOP2f1 which is in type MatOfPoint2f
              double approxDistance = Imgproc.arcLength(contour2f, true)*0.02;
              Imgproc.approxPolyDP(contour2f, approxCurve, approxDistance, true);

              //Convert back to MatOfPoint
              MatOfPoint points = new MatOfPoint( approxCurve.toArray() );

              // Get bounding rect of contour
              Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(points);
             int xoffset=rect.x;
             int yoffset=rect.y;
              for (int y = 0; y < rect.height; y++) {
                    for (int x = 0; x < rect.width; x++) {
                        if (yoffset>1 & xoffset>1)
                        {
                        outlie.add(new Point(xoffset+x,yoffset+y));
                        ylist.add(yoffset+y);
                        xlist.add(xoffset+x);
                        }
                    }
                    }


              }
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the threshold of the canny controlled the amount of contours in the resulting image.